# Take the nth column of a file and make them input to a shell script

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file (encrypted_pass.txt) with 2 columns:

```
user1 encrypted_pass1
user2 encrypted_pass2 
user3 encrypted_pass3
...
```

user passwords (2nd column) are encrypted. I have a shell script that decrypts the encrypted passwords. The script takes an encrypted password as the input and decrypts it:

```
decryptor.sh -d encrypted_password
```

What I want to do is to take encrypted passwords from the file (column 2), decrypt it and write the dcrypted password to a new file.
Thus, the output file should be:

```
user1 decrypted_pass1
user2 decrypted_pass2 
user3 decrypted_pass3
...
```

How can I do this by awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use something like this:

```
cut -f2 -d " " input_file | xargs -n1 decryptor.sh -d > output_file
```

Comment: This helped me feed the decryptor.sh script taking the second column of the file as the input. I had to perform some more text processing after this and realized my goal. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `system` procedure to call your script from inside `awk`:

```
awk '{printf $1" "; system("decryptor.sh -d " $2)}' file1 > file2
```

Comment: It does not work :s
`-sh-4.1$ cat encrypted_pass.txt`
`NULL    NULL`
`admin I5pxTzWzKPo5OVWXSTtxWA==`
`NULL    NULL`

`-sh-4.1$ awk '{printf $1" "; system("decryptor.sh -d  " $2)}' ne_cli_encrypted.txt`
`NULL admin NULL -sh-4.1$`

Comment: @Murat What does `awk '{printf $1" "; system("echo " $2)}'` show?

Comment: @Murat Also, what is NULL? It doesn't appear in the example provided in question.

Comment: If the user&password info is not present for a given NE (these entries belong to Network Elements and it relates with another file based on the order of the entries), we have NULL for both user and password info. The script does not decrypt NULL values.
 `awk '{printf $1" "; system("echo " $2)}' ne_cli_encrypted.txt` command prints exactly the same input file: 
`-sh-4.1$ awk '{printf $1" "; system("echo " $2)}' ne_cli_encrypted.txt` 
`NULL NULL`
`isadmin I5pxTzWzKPo5OVWXSTtxWA==`
`NULL NULL`

Comment: @Murat please edit your question and update information about input file, and the output of the command. In the comments section the code is not properly formated and is hard to understand what the output is.